# Why is Aspose.Cells cutting off the top half of my text when I export to PDF (or TIFF or XPS)?

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose-cells

I'm using Aspose.Cells to create a report to be exported to both Excel and PDF.  In cell A1, I have some text that I've given a font size of 20.  When I save this workbook to a PDF file, the top half of the text is getting cut off.

Here's a screenshot of the PDf file:

[image]

I tried adjusting the height of the first row using AutoFitRow(int), but that's not fixing my problem.  My code to reproduce this is very short:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program.Licenses(); //only sets licenses

    var wb = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
    var cell = ws.Cells[0, 0];

    cell.Value = "Text is cutoff";

    var style = cell.GetStyle();
    style.Font.Size = 20;
    cell.SetStyle(style);

    ws.AutoFitRow(1); //doesn't prevent text cutoff

    wb.Save(@"C:\Users\guest\Desktop\file2.pdf", Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Pdf);
}
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing the top half of my text to be cutoff?  the text is also getting cut off if I export to Tiff or XPS.  It looks fine however if I export to XLSX.

Version Information:

- Aspose.Cells.DLL: Runtime Version = v2.0.50727, Version = 8.1.2.0
- Aspose.Pdf.DLL: Runtime Version = v4.0.30319, Version 9.5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the problem:

```
ws.AutoFitRow(1); //doesn't prevent text cutoff
```

The argument should be zero, not one.  If I change that to the below, it'll work.

```
ws.AutoFitRow(0);
```

Edit: If the cells are merged, you need to use AutoFitterOptions to tell the code to fit merged cells:

```
ws.AutoFitRow(0, 0, 1, new Aspose.Cells.AutoFitterOptions() { AutoFitMergedCells = true });
```